# What does this condition in the for loop mean?

Tags: data-structures, loops, java

I found a solution of exercise C-8.28 from Data Structures and Algorithms in Java (6th Edition), but I'm having trouble understanding how the for loop condition works here.

```
for(Position<E> c : T.children(p))
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the condition in the for loop means. From what I've learned so far the for loop is formatted with 3 conditions so I'm not familiar with it and I'm trying to understand the concept behind this solution. I looked it up online, but I haven't been able to find another instance of this, though I did find something about the format `for(type variable : collection)` in a greek Data Structures book by Panagiotis D. Mpozanis. Yet, I don't understand it. Could you help me a bit with this?

Comment: that's a Java construction which means that `c` will take on each of the elements of `T.children(p)` in turn.  Sometimes, like [in the docs, here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) they call it an "enhanced for loop".

Comment: Oh , so technically if the position given is the root then the recursion can start from the leaves and come back all the way to the root for the addition? How does the recursion work when there are more than one children, does the method run simultaneously for both?

Comment: no, it won't run simultaneously - you should think of it as like writing `for(int i = 0; i <T.children(p).size(); i++)` and then writing `T.children(p).get(i)` (or whatever syntax is appropriate) in place of `c` in the loop body.

Comment: I see~ Thank you, it makes sense to me now!

Comment: The link is not to a public site. Please change that.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Change it how? By removing it? Should I state that it's from a non public site or should I put the link from it's public starting page?

Comment: After all, the exercise is irrelevant, only the for construct matters.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay, I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a For-each loop. in your example: `for(Position<E> c : T.children(p))` the **c** is a variable of type **Position<E>** and it takes it's value in each iterate of the for from a **list** or an **array** or whatever container of type **Position<E>**, meaning the **T.children(p)** must be a container of type **Position<E>**.

For a more simple example in order to understand the mechanism of the For-each loop here is an example: Consider a class named Person and an App class where App creates instances of Person and prints it using the For-each loop:

Person:

```
package org.example;

public class Person {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String gender;

    private byte age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, byte age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public byte getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

App:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    static void generate(List<Person> personList) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            personList.add(new Person("John" + i, "Smith" + i, "Male", (byte) (i + 20)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        generate(personList);
        System.out.println();
        for (Person person : personList) {
            System.out.println("First Name: " + person.getFirstName() + "; Last Name: " +
                    person.getLastName() + "; Gender: " + person.getGender() + "; Age: " + person.getAge());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Note in the App.main in the for loop it's the same as your loop but it takes a person in each iterate in the order it appears in the list and prints it.

For further explanation you can read at [For-each loop in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!